# How to hide single element in map function in react native onPress?

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, render, react-native-maps

Suppose I'm given an object of elements, which I loop via map and rendered. When I click on one of the lists, I expect that element to hide from the render.

```html
Object.keys(this.state.doctors).map((uid, i) => { return (
<View style={styles.doctorContainer} key={uid}>
  <View style={styles.imgCircleContainer}>
    <View>
      <Image style={styles.userImg} source={require( '../Images/Naseebullah.jpg')} resizeMode="contain" />
      <View style={styles.imgOverlay} />
    </View>
  </View>

  <View>
    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 15, color: '#bccad0'}}>{this.state.doctors[uid].name}</Text>
    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, color: 'rgba(188, 202, 208, 0.7)'}}>{this.state.doctors[uid].profession}</Text>
  </View>

  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.folllowBtn} onPress={()=> Database.followDoctor( this.state.doctors[uid].name, this.state.doctors[uid].profession, uid, this.state.type, this.state.healthAlert )}>
    <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 13, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center'}}>Follow</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
) })
```

So when `Database.followDoctor()` is called onPress. That element should hide. Not the whole list. How can this be achieved?

I come from angularjs background, wherein angular we have whats called local variables assigned to each element in the loop, and we can condition it. But how can this be achieved in react native?

## Edit

The method followDoctor() is not helpful because it is a method that communicated to firebase server

```js
static followDoctor(msgTo, profession, uid, type, healthAlert) {
  User().then(user => {
    firebase.app().database().ref(`/Users/${user.uid}/Doctors/${uid}`).set({
      name: msgTo,
      profession: profession
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("successfully added to DoctorsList!");
      this.initialiseMessagesDB(msgTo, healthAlert, uid).then(() => {
        //this.setMessage(uid, type);
      })
      //this.setMessage(uid, type, healthAlert, userName);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  });
}
```

The issue lies within the onPress function. If we can somehow do something in the onPress() function of the button and hide the element, then it would be great.

## What is my issue then?

The problem isn't that I'm unable to filter them out. In fact, my current implementation does filter them out. But the issue is timing, between the click event and hiding of the element. Because the click even goes to firebase and appends the object (which adds the doctor into the object) it creates few milliseconds delay. I would like to hid the element as soon as it is clicked, and in background I do the firebase checking and what not.

Comment: Could you please share all of your code, including the source of `Database.followDoctor`?

Comment: Please check my edit above. @AlexYuly

Comment: Do you need it to show again? one way would be to filter it out of this.state.doctors when it's pressed, which will re-render the list without that item. Also you might want to consider using flatlist for better performance

Comment: If you want it to be persistent then you should always filter out the doctors the user is following before setting this.state.doctors and when one is pressed and the relation is created, fetch the doctors list again.

Comment: @MattAft no, I dont have to show it again. Once clicked, it should hide. The current implementation that I have does hide it, but when it's clicked, it take long (about 400 milliseconds) before it hides. Thats because in my setState({}) it access firebase and adds the doctor and then filters the list. But I would like to hide it streightaway and the filter can happen at the background

Comment: Just filter out the current doctor? the whole point of react/react native is to use the design pattern they tell you to use, to make it work the best.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I understand that. The problem isn't that I'm unable to filter them out. In fact, my current implementation does filter them out. But the issue is timing, between the click event and hiding of the element. Because the click even goes to firebase and appends the object (which adds the doctor into the object) it creates few milliseconds delay. I would like to hid the element as soon as it is clicked, and in background I do the firebase checking and what not

Comment: then in `followDoctor`, filter it out and update the state before going to firebase

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to filter it out of the list. Create a boolean in the object called `visible` and apply a `filter` method before the `map` - something like:

`Object.keys(this.state.doctors).filter(uid => uid.visible).map((uid, i) => { return (`

And then when you call `Database.followDoctor()` you toggle that flag.

If you don't want those flags stored in your DB, then you can add them to the data (initially setting to *true*) when loading from the DB and stripping them before saving.